What is wrong with my integration of $\int e^x \arcsin \left(e^x\right) d x$
Im doing the QCAA Specialist Maths 2022 Paper 1 Question 19, my answer differs from the states answers fundamentally when graphing. On inspection a function disappears when integrating, as in when deriving the integration it is gone.

$$f(x)=\int e^x \arcsin \left(e^x\right) d x$$

I tried this for a long time might, ignore c values they have some mistakes and are not relevant to the exact integration thats casuing the problem, its just the u subsitution integration after the integration by parts thats the problem.
Its the $u=e^x$ and $du/dx = e^x$ subsitution, the step I take after my initial integration by parts where I integrate in terms of $du$. When deriving that integral it does not get my original function before integrating. Its missing an $e^x$ factor. Its the $\arcsin(e^x)$ derivative which I saw the integral of, in the step that had a penciled square around it and the integrations I did with that term. That is the problem integration.
My teachers could not help me either and just TOLD me I found some exception or glitch or something after they worked through it for an hour or so. I think its just an integration error. Please help its really messing with my head going into my external exam.
My work:
$$\begin{aligned}\\
& \quad\\
& w=\arcsin \left(e^x\right), \quad v^{\prime}=e^x \\
& w^{\prime}=\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2 x}}},\quad v=e^x \\
& f(x)=e^x \arcsin \left(e^x\right)-\int \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2 x}}} e^x d x \\
& \quad\\
& u=e^x, \quad \frac{d u}{d x}=e^x \\
& f(x)=e^x \arcsin e^x-\int \frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \frac{d u}{d x} d x \\
& f(x)=e^x \arcsin e^x-\frac{\arcsin e^{x}}{2} + C \\
& \quad\\
& 0=e^0 \arcsin e^0-\frac{\arcsin e^{0}}{2} + C \\
& 0=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}+C \\
& C=-\frac{\pi}{4} \\
& \quad\\
& f(x)=\arcsin{(e^x)}\left(e^x-\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi}{4}\\
\end{aligned}$$

That's a lot of words without telling us what the question is.

Its in the image, its just the integration the question is nothing special. That integration is wrong in some way but i cant find how and my teachers couldnt help me

Welcome to Math.SE! ... I'm afraid your hand-written solution isn't very clear. What's your answer? What's the "states answer"? What exactly are the differences? (Note that instead of images, you should format mathematical expressions using MathJax; see this tutorial.) ... Also, your text is quite confusing. I don't understand what you mean by "on inspection a funnction dissapears in integration" and "I tried this for a long time might, ignore c values they have some mistakes"; or what "exception or glitch" you might have come across.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hey guys i tired making it abit more clear sorry i cant work out this format for maths thing im sort of studying for an exam at the same time sorry

@DevTheHall Avoid using the same variable for 2 different substitutions. Using $u(x)$ for IBP and then u-sub confuses the reader. Hence, for IBP, I changed the variable to $w(x)$.

The integral we are trying to evaluate is $f(x)=\int{e^x\sin^{-1}{e^x}\text{d}x}$. The initial condition is $f(0)=0$. The original question is also available on the QCAA website here. We can start of with a $u$ substitution, letting $u=e^x$; $$u=e^x,\text{d}u=e^x\text{d}x,\int{e^x\sin^{-1}{e^x}\text{d}x}\Rightarrow\int{\sin^{-1}(u)\text{d}u}$$
Employing integration by parts:
$$
\begin{matrix}
&D&I\\
+&\sin^{-1}(u)&1\\
-&\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}&u
\end{matrix}
$$
Which turns the integral into: $$\int{\sin^{-1}(u)\text{d}u}=u\sin^{-1}(u)-\int{\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}}\text{d}u$$
The use of another substitution $t=1-u^2$ evaluates to: $$t=1-u^2,\text{d}t=-2u\text{d}u,\int{\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\text{d}u}\Rightarrow-\int{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\text{d}t}=-\sqrt{t}$$
Undoing the substitution: $$u\sin^{-1}(u)+\sqrt{t}=u\sin^{-1}(u)+\sqrt{1-u^2}=e^x\sin^{-1}(e^x)+\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}+C$$
As for the initial condition, $f(0)=0$, so $$e^0\sin^{-1}(e^0)+\sqrt{1-e^{2\times0}}+C=0\rightarrow C=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Therefore: $$f(x)=e^x\sin^{-1}(e^x)+\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
